# How to retain more than 16 digits in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, integer

I am getting an 20 digit number from API call. I want to retain the number as it is in javascript. How can I achieve this?
For Eg : Response from API is 123456789123456789. I want to convert this to string or retain it as number(if its possible) in javascript. Result desired "123456789123456789".

Comment: ""+ number ;) ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I handle numbers bigger than 17-digits in Firefox/IE7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086575/how-can-i-handle-numbers-bigger-than-17-digits-in-firefox-ie7)

Comment: 1. Add some code. 2. How do you get the number from the "API call"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your API call function name is `myAPICall`:

```
var result = myAPICall() + "";
```